# "jumpy" jquery image slider navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using a jquery image slider/plugin where the thumbnails act as navigation. I have noticed that they are very “jumpy” in that when I first hover over an image the entire selection moves back and forth. Also when I move my cursor away from the thumbnails they do the same. Any ideas how to prevent/minimize this?

[Live site.](http://urbanpalate.com/instyle-mag-ming-by-mango/)

Answer (score 1):

Tis because the slider is based on the mouse position, but the thumbnails only move when you hover over the thumbnail navigation. So when you move off the nav, move the cursor a long way to the left and then put it back on the nav, it is of course going to jump a lot.

a) use a different method of scrolling the thumbnail nav, not based on mouse position

b) make the thumbnail nav scroll all the time, regardless of whether you are hovered over it or not